# React Native How to prevent images from flickering when switching tabs on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm implementing a React Native app with tab navigation.
In 'Home' tab, there are around 30 images.
When I switch to another tab and then get back to 'Home', images flickers without source change. Please refer to below gif.

[image]

I'm not really sure but I think the reason the image is flashing is because it is reloaded.
This occurs on Android only and occurs when tabs are switched.
I couldn't find this when I moved to another screen in the same tab.
Please refer to below gif.

[image]

I would like to make images not flashing once they are loaded.

Comment: Normally tabs are not re-rendered upon subsequent visits. Are you working with Expo CLI?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with Expo CLI

Comment: I use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image for image and it's much better then default image of react-native and it also cache images automatically but i don't think it will work in expo.

Comment: Thanks @HardikChavda I hope expo will support react-native-fast-image as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are working with the Asset Lib from Expo. There you can preload your images so that they are cached in the device. You can install it with `expo install expo-asset`

```
import { useAssets } from 'expo-asset';
function App() {
  // Preload your images here
  const [assets] = useAssets([require('path/to/asset.jpg'), require('path/to/other.png')]);

  if (!assets) {
    // Return Loading Component (ActivityIndicator)
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Loaded {assets.length} assets!</Text>
      <Image source={require('path/to/asset.jpg')} />
      <Image source={require('path/to/other.png')} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

With the code this should no longer occur